# How can I write max and min number in a randomly created array. PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone of you can help me? I have no idea how to do this. This is my php. I would be grateful if you could help me:)))

```
$cifra = $_POST["cifra"];
for($i=1;$i<=$cifra;$i++)
{
   $nc = rand(1,99);
   if ($nc/2 != floor($nc/2)) 
     echo "<span style=\"color: black\">$nc </span>";
   else
     echo $nc." "; 
}

echo "xxxxx ";
```

Comment: elaborate your question, I didnt understand what you are asking

Comment: I have to write the maximum and minimum number from that array so when I refresh the page, the array will change--> so the min and max numbers

Comment: Where is your array?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But, I think you want this:

```
$cifra = $_POST["cifra"];
$arr = array();
  for($i=1;$i<=$cifra;$i++)
  {
    $nc = rand(1,99);
    if ($nc/2 != floor($nc/2)) 
      echo "<span 
      style=\"color: black\">
      $nc </span>";

    else
      echo $nc." ";

    $arr[] = $nc; 
  }

echo '<br>Max: ' . max($arr);
echo '<br>Min: ' . min($arr);
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much, you saved my highschool life

Comment: @MartinReck, Cool. So. please select the answer as solved